How to configure WireMock to match a specific query parameter (Object) format in Java? [Quarkus]
I'm currently working on integration testing for a Java application using WireMock. One of the HTTP GET requests sent by the application includes a query parameter named sortOrder. This parameter needs to be matched in a specific format, such as TransactionSearchCriteria.SortOrder(property=merchantId,direction=DESC). However, my WireMock stub is not correctly recognizing this format when matching incoming requests.
As a response im getting a Resource not found .
this is my wiremock file
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/my/path",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": {
        "equalTo": "application/json"
      },
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": {
        "equalTo": "test"
      }
    },
    "queryParameters": {
      "x": {
        "equalTo": "0"
      },
      "y": {
        "equalTo": "2"
      },
      "myObj.property": {
        "equalTo": "prop1"
      },
      "myObj.direction": {
        "equalTo": "desc"
      },
      "startDate": {
        "equalTo": "2022-01-16T01:00:00Z"
      },
      "endDate": {
        "equalTo": "2024-01-17T01:00:00Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "bodyFileName": "response.json"
  }
}

and this is how i call it  in the test :
@Test
  void myTestOk() {
    var myObj = new SortOrder("merchantId", Sort.Direction.DESC);
    var searchCriteria = SearchCriteria.builder()
        .x(0)
        .y(2)
        .startDate(LocalDateTime.of(2022, Month.JANUARY, 16, 1, 0, 0)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant())
        .endDate(LocalDateTime.of(2024, Month.JANUARY, 17, 1, 0, 0)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant())
        .sort(myObj)
        .build();

    var myPage = restClient.getTransactions(searchCriteria);

and this is the log when i run the test
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
[path regex] /my/path
                                                             /my/path?startDate=2022-01-16T
                                                           | 01%3A00%3A00Z&endDate=2024-01-
                                                             17T01%3A00%3A00Z&x
                                                           | =0&y=2&myObj=
                                                             SearchCriteria.SortOrd
                                                           | er%28property%3Dprop1%2C
                                                             +direction%3DDESC%29
                                                           |
Accept: application/json                                   | Accept: application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: TEST                            | Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: TEST
                                                           |
Query: pageNumber = 0                                      | pageNumber: 0
Query: pageSize = 2                                        | pageSize: 2
Query: sortOrder.property = merchantId
Query: sortOrder.direction = desc                                | sortOrder: <<<<< Query is not 
                                                                                        present
property=merchantId,direction=DESC                         | TransactionSearchCriteria.
                                                             SortOrder(property=merchantId,
                                                           | direction=DESC)
Query: startDate = 2022-01-16T01:00:00Z                    | startDate: 2022-01-16T01:00:00Z
Query: endDate = 2024-01-17T01:00:00Z                      | endDate: 2024-01-17T01:00:00Z
                                                           |
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

So mainly the problem is when im passing myObj as a queryparam :
@RestQuery("sortOrder")
  private SortOrder sort;


Do you need the myObj attributes to be part of the matching criteria at all? If you're not also creating a stub where everything else is the same but those aren't, then I suggest just removing those matchers completely.

Hello, yes i need to know the property and the direction of the sort in the matching criteria (mandatory criteria's) .

Looks like your web framework is serialising sortOrder incorrectly - TransactionSearchCriteria.SortOrder(property=merchantId,direction=DESC) looks pretty suspect.
